# Cannot get an image from requests.get

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, get, python-imaging-library

I have 2 images that I want to process with some logic in python.
Here the 2 URLs to the images:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png
https://www.hogan.com/fashion/hogan/HXW4350DM10NCR0RSZ/HXW4350DM10NCR0RSZ-02.png

To get these images I wrote the following script:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

img.show()
```

This piece of code is ok and I correctly get the image.

But, with the second image, I cannot receive any response from the get method.

```
url = "https://www.hogan.com/fashion/hogan/HXW4350DM10NCR0RSZ/HXW4350DM10NCR0RSZ-02.png"

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

img.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

python 3.9.4
requests 2.25.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the second url **requires** an important **header parameter**, the [user-agent](https://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/)

Let's add it into your request:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://www.hogan.com/fashion/hogan/HXW4350DM10NCR0RSZ/HXW4350DM10NCR0RSZ-02.png"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

img.show()
```

**How do we know if some website requires User-agent?**
We just don't know, but we assume that if the browser can get the image properly and a simple request does not, it is missing something, and most of the websites requires headers to validate your request